# How to do an aggregate and transpose in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I would like to do some aggregates such as collect_list on non-numeric fields and then transpose to multiple columns based on a different column.

Here is a simple data set and my desired result.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("John", 'Male', 'GA'),
    ("Mary", "Female", 'GA'),
    ("Alex", "Male", "NY"),
    ("Ana", "Female", "NY"),
    ("Amy", "Female", "NY")   
], ["Name", "gender", "state"])
```

I'm able to group by 2 fields as follows.

```
(df
 .groupBy('state', 'gender')
 .agg(collect_list('Name'))
).show()
```

```
+-----+------+------------------+
|state|gender|collect_list(Name)|
+-----+------+------------------+
|   NY|  Male|            [Alex]|
|   GA|  Male|            [John]|
|   GA|Female|            [Mary]|
|   NY|Female|        [Ana, Amy]|
+-----+------+------------------+
```

How can I transpose it to two fields based on the gender field? Here is what I'm looking for.

```
state |   male   | female
--------------------------
GA    | ['John'] | ['Mary']
NY    | ['Alex'] | ['Ana', 'Amy']
```

Comment: `df.groupBy('state').pivot('gender').agg(collect_list('Name')).show()`

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose using [`pivot()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=pivot#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) after a `groupby`. Spark also has a [`collect_list()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=pivot#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) aggregation.

```
df.groupBy('state').pivot('gender').agg(F.collect_list('Name')).show()

# +-----+----------+------+
# |state|    Female|  Male|
# +-----+----------+------+
# |   NY|[Ana, Amy]|[Alex]|
# |   GA|    [Mary]|[John]|
# +-----+----------+------+
```